# How do you use JSON.stringify in a custom toJSON method?

Tags: javascript, json

So, JSON.stringify provides a great way to turn a JS object like:

```
var baz = {"foo":1, "bar":someFunction};
```

in to a JSON string like:

```
{"foo":1}
```

It does this with an optional second argument that controls which fields should be serialized:

```
JSON.stringify(baz, ["foo"]);
```

That's great, but there's a problem.  Let's say your "baz" is actually the property of another object, and you want to serialize that other object:

```
someObject.baz = {"foo":1, "bar":someFunction};
JSON.stringify(someObject, ["baz"]);
```

Well, normally you would just define a toJSON method on baz, eg.:

```
someObject.baz = {"foo":1, "bar":someFunction};
someObject.baz.toJSON = function() { /* logic to "toJSON" baz*/ }
JSON.stringify(someObject, ["baz"]);
```

Now, as I mentioned earlier, we have the perfect logic to "toJSON" baz already:

```
someObject.baz.toJSON = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(baz, ["foo"]);
}
```

but if you try putting that in to your toJSON, you'll get a recursion error, because stringify will trigger the toJSON, which will trigger the stringify, which will ... :-(

You can work around this with a hack:

```
someObject.baz.toJSON = function() {
    var oldToJON = this.toJSON;
    this.toJSON = null;
    var ret = JSON.stringify(baz, ["foo"]);
    this.toJSON = oldToJON;
    return ret;
}
```

But ... that just seems wrong.  So, my question is: is there any way you can utilize the nifty built-in serialization power of JSON.stringify *inside* a toJSON method of an object (without having to hide the toJSON method itself during the stringify operation)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) says:

> A toJSON method does not serialize: it returns the value represented by the name/value pair that should be serialized, or undefined if nothing should be serialized.

So you are simply expected to return the value that you want serialized. In your case, `baz.toJSON` should simply return the portion of the `baz` object that you want serialized:

```
someObject.baz.toJSON = function() {
  return { foo: this.foo };
};
```

Comment: So then if I only want to serialize certain fields, I have to do:

Comment: someObject.baz.toJSON = function() {
  var ret = {};
  for (var property in this) {
    if (!property in listOfPropertiesToSerialize) continue;
    ret[property] = this[property;
  }
  return ret;
};

Comment: There's no way to just provide the list of fields and let the the built-in JSON stuff (whether it's Crockford's or the browser-supplied ones) filter things out, the way the stringify method does?

Comment: @machineghost: You could do that, but look out for chained properties and make sure to use `this.hasOwnProperty(property)`. If your list of properties is static, you could just use object notation to directly build a new object. **Edit:** No, I don't believe that is possible. `toJSON` works differently from `stringify`.

Comment: Ok, new problem: if I setup someObject.baz.toJSON as you suggest, and then call "JSON.stringify(someObject, ['baz'])" it only serializes the "baz" field (if any) of baz.  In other words, the stringify filter argument seems to be applying to all of the sub-objects as well.  Is there any way to work around this, or am I basically just stuck with assembling my JSON by hand (without stringify) if I want to have sub-objects defining their own toJSON?

Comment: @machineghost: Skip the filter and add a `toJSON` method to `someObject` as well, that only returns the `baz` property.