# Creating a Json Cookie Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a cookie array using jquery's json. Here is the script which works so far except for the array part. Can someone please tell me how I can do an array like this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       //The database value will go here...
       var cookievalue= {'tid1':'ticvalue1','thid1':'thidvalue1','tid2':'ticvalue2','thid2':'thidvalue2'};

       //Create a cookie and have it expire in 1 day.
       $.cookie('cookietest', cookievalue, { expires: 1 });

       //Write the value of the cookie...
       document.write($.cookie('cookietest'));

    </script>
```

The problem I'm having is when I pass the array to the cookie it is storing `[object object]` instead of the array values. So if I loop through the data then I will multiple cookies instead of one cookie with the array value stored in

Comment: I think they call what I am trying to do is Associative Array. Sorta of like what is happening here but in row format for multiple row data: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/loop-key-value-pairs-associative-array-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You're creating one object with those properties. And your're using single quotes instead of doubles (as far as i know in json you have to specify an String with double quotes).

Try that:

```
      var cookievalue= [{"tid1":"ticvalue1"},{"thid1":"thidvalue1"},{"tid2":"ticvalue2"},{"thid2":"thidvalue2"}];
```

So after parsing you get following: structure

```
cookievalue[0].tid1 == "ticvalue1"<br/>
cookievalue[1].thid1 == "thidvalue1"<br/>
cookievalue[2].tid2 == "ticvalue2"<br/>
cookievalue[3].thid2 == "thidvalue2"<br/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work its returning [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] Any other suggestions? Thanks by the way!!

Comment: so what do you expect? simple those values as an array? in that case: `var cookievalue= ["ticvalue1","thidvalue1","ticvalue2","thidvalue2"];`

Comment: Well I trying to create rows of data. The actual goal is to populate that array with data from a database in to rows for ex: Row = tid1 = ticvalue, thid1 = thisvalue1 Then Row 2 tid2 = tidvalue2, thid2 = thidvalue 2 and so on...

Comment: @Genosite I am new to json and learning but never used that before would you be able to provide me a small example how to do it or direct me somewhere to learn? Thanks!

Comment: You could get the data from both examples above. If that's not how you would access the data red from the cookie then you need to tell me how. Simply post the line used for it, e.g. `row.tid1 = cookievalue[0]`

Comment: JSON.stringify(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289282/how-do-you-use-json-stringify-in-a-custom-tojson-method and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach not really sure. I guess at this point just trying to code it the proper way. The goal is to store each row in to one cookie and then later pull that cookie and get each row of data and display it. What would you recommend me do being new to json and trying to do it proper?

Comment: JSON is just a way to encode data in a form whitch both human and machines could read easily. The proper way of using it is to respect the syntax. How your datastructure will look like is another thing which depends on how you need to use the data. For that I could not give an advice without knowing what' happening with the data before and after. But you should have a look at: http://www.json.org/ and specially here: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: To store the data of each row and easily access it later I suppose following: `var cookievalue = [{"tid1":"ticvalue1","thid1":"thidvalue1"},{"tid2":"ticvalue2","thid2":"thidvalue2"}];` So you could acces later like `cookievalue[0].tid1 == "ticvalue1"; cookievalue[0].thid1 == "thidvalue1"; cookievalue[1].tid2 == "ticvalue2"; cookievalue[1].thid2 == "thidvalue2";`

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach why when I use your code it returns [object Object],[object Object]? 
        var cookievalue = [{"tid1":"ticvalue1","thid1":"thidvalue1"},{"tid2":"ticvalue2","thid2":"thidvalu‌​e2"}]; alert(cookievalue); Is that normal?

Comment: Yes that's normal. Because `{"tid1":"ticvalue1"}` defines an object. This Object gets an property `tid1` with specified value `ticvalue1`. If you want another structure show me what you expect.

Comment: SORRY: I just red your comment in your question about: "Associative Array." (in JS an associative array is just an object). If its that what you want you just were right with the sample! But then I have to ask what was your problem in first? Got an error? when yes: which error and where it happend?

Comment: After reading again I suspect that your problem was that `document.write($.cookie('cookietest'));` results in `[object Object]`? If so then that's not a problem, it's just the case that an "associative array" IS an object! So you have to get the values like this: `for(var index in cookievalue) {
   alert( index + " : " + cookievalue[index]);
  }`

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach the problem I'm having is when I pass the array to the cookie it is storing [object object] instead of the array values. So if I loop through the data then I will multiple cookies instead of one cookie with the array value stored in.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem I'm having is when I pass the array to the cookie it is storing [object object] instead of the array values. So if I loop through the data then I will multiple cookies instead of one cookie with the array value stored in.

Now you're plain-talking! So we could help you without thousands of comments ;)

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var cookieValueString = JSON.stringify( 
                    [
                        {
                            'column1':'row1col1',
                            'column2':'row1col2'
                        },
                        {
                            'column1':'row2col1',
                            'colum2':'row2col2'
                        }
                    ] 
                );
                $.cookie('cookietest', cookieValueString, { expires: 1 });

                var arrayFromCookie = JSON.parse($.cookie('cookietest'));
                for(var i = 0; i < arrayFromCookie.length; i++) {
                    alert("Row #" + i
                           + "- Column #1: " + arrayFromCookie[i].column1
                           + " - Column #2: " + arrayFromCookie[i].column2);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```